# why doesnt this open the webviewer when i press the button?

Tags: android, button, webview, click, android-sdk-2.3

So i have this button that I would like it to open a webviewer when the button is pressed.

Here is the xml where the button is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/signIn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:src="@drawable/signin"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here the class code for the click button

```
public class SignIn extends Activity {
ImageView img;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.signIn);
    signIn();

}
public void signIn() {
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignIn.this, WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

here is where i have the webviwer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/webView1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

And here is the webviewer class

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity{

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
}
```

When click nothing happens, I also edited the manifest to have internet access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a small correction. In XML you are using "ImageButton" but in java file your are using "ImageView".

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/signIn"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="61dp"
android:src="@drawable/signin"
android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is wrong to write in XML ImageButton and in java file to search for an ImageView by id.

Use an ImageView or an ImageButton!

if you want to use an imageView don forget to make it clicable.